# Derive keys from strings in array in typescript to define object property names

Tags: typescript

I want to define the keys in an object match a 2-dimensional arrays first items.

```
export const ProductInfos = [
  ["description", "Description"],
] as const
type ProductInfoTypes = typeof ProductInfos[number][0]

export type Product = {
  id: string
  //[key in typeof ProductInfos[number][0]]: string
}
```

So here `Product` should end up with a property `description" that accepts a string.

However my `[key in typeof ProductInfos[number][0]]: string` does not compile

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464)
The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.ts(2361)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in type mapper `Record` and  type intersection like below:

```
export const ProductInfos = [
  ["description", "Description"],
] as const
type ProductInfoTypes = typeof ProductInfos[number][0]

type ProdcutDescription =  Record<ProductInfoTypes,string>

 type Base = {
  id: string
}

type Product = Base & ProdcutDescription

const product : Product ={
  id:"asdsa",
  description : "as" //ok 
foo:"ere" // error
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wApQgEwK4IwCSyAZhKnALxwDaAUHHQEQ7CoJQCWYMXKzADRxmAEXacefAQF1B9GXACGlJGhj0YATzDA4WXAWJkIAFR3tqcbboil92fIRLlUtZHgC2AI2BQZtAAMMvSaFg64CHgw4hzcvPzIVnAASsBIUDgAPAZOxuTmuqiC6NzIAOYAfKHW4QBCKno0AN6McFw4AFxwpVwV9AC+oTZ6uUZWDah6AGQROFExEvHSyKFq6HBgjuPdY4TUrUwdncwqOKhKQm1scVKJcN2nqDjM9OQQJ37AzHAA9L9wPzYKCDUJAA)

Comment: Thanks, that was quick. I knew about the `Record` but didn't think of using it with intersection. TIL

Comment: How to make *description* optional in `Product`?

Comment: Sorry, already found answer to my question: `type Product = Base & Partial<ProductDescription>`

Comment: @basil you can use `Partial` to achieve what you want: `type ProdcutDescription = Partial< Record<ProductInfoTypes,string>>`